# Xamarin Android ImageView Zoom

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using **Xamarin C#** to develop an android application.

I have a view that displays two ImageViews for comparison purposes.

I am currently looking for a way to zoom into each individual ImageView displayed on the view.

I've found the below link which seems to be referenced on a lot of answers which extends on the ImageView however the link does not exist anymore. Anyone have an idea on where to get this code since it has been removed or any ideas on how to achieve this?

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroidToolkit/blob/master/MonoDroidToolkit/com.refractored.monodroidtoolkit/ScaleImageView.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe xamarin component PhotoView can help you. https://components.xamarin.com/view/photoview

Description:

> PhotoView aims to help produce an easily usable implementation of a
>   zooming Android ImageView.

Also, Here is the correct link to ScaleImageView (from your question)
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroidToolkit/blob/master/src/MonoDroidToolkit/ScaleImageView.cs

Comment: Ah, thanks. I got the ScaleImageView working straight away and seems to do the job. Will be sure to check out the photoview component when I get a gap. Appreciate it!